# Yolo v3 Loss Function fails when reloaded during load_model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, yolo

I've been trying to save a Yolo v3 model and then Load it back from from an h5 file.
When saving I use the checkpoint (ModelCheckpoint) to save the model (with the parameter save_weights_only
set to False in order to save the WHOLE model).

However, when I tried to recover the same model by using the keras load_model function, I initially get a yolo_head function not found error.

I then tried to add the function as a parameter to the load function as in:

```
{"yolo_head":yolo_head}
```

Now, the issue becomes: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" because somehow, there's an error in the loss function (yolo_loss, line 444) when loaded dynamically.

Apparently, the binary code of the loss function is hard copied into the h5 file.

My question is this:
Is there a better/simpler YOLO loss function that I can use THAT DOES NOT refer to other functions or can be easily reloaded?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT 1: Additional Code Snippets,
Keras Checkpoint Callback definition:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    os.path.join(log_dir, "checkpoint.h5"),
    monitor="val_loss",
    save_weights_only=False,
    save_best_only=True,
    period=1,
)
```

Checkpoint added to model training:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
        data_generator_wrapper(
            lines[:num_train], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes
        ),
        steps_per_epoch=max(1, num_train // batch_size),
        validation_data=data_generator_wrapper(
            lines[num_train:], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes
        ),
        validation_steps=max(1, num_val // batch_size),
        epochs=epoch1,
        initial_epoch=0,
        callbacks=[logging, checkpoint],
    )
```

Trying to load the same file 'checkpoint.h5' after pre-training ended:

```
weights_path = os.path.join(log_dir, "checkpoint.h5")
model = load_model(weights_path, {"yolo_head":yolo_head, "tf":tf, "box_iou":box_iou,'<lambda>': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred})
```

Here is the error stack trace:

> File "2_Training/Train_YOLO.py", line 206, in 
> model = load_model(weights_path, {"yolo_head":yolo_head, "tf":tf,
> "box_iou":box_iou,'': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred})

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/**init**.py", line 55, in deserialize
printable_module_name='layer')

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
list(custom_objects.items())))

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1032, in from_config
process_node(layer, node_data)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 991, in process_node
layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in **call**
output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)

File "/Users/nkwedi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 687, in call
return self.function(inputs, **arguments)

File "/Users/nkwedi/Documents/MyProjects/Eroscope/EyeDetectionYOLO/2_Training/src/keras_yolo3/yolo3/model.py", line 444, in yolo_loss
anchors[anchor_mask[l]],

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: You have to provide all details, not just parts of errors that make no sense in isolation. Please include code and full tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution for me was to use a Cloud Based Training Platform like Google Collab.
Here's a link to a workable Collab Notebook with GPU enabled:
[YOLO v3 Google Collab Tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Mh2HP_Mfxoao6qNFbhfV3u28tG8jAVGk#scrollTo=VHw00Cro8ONr)